# Chrome Extension - Upload CSV File to Dropbox Format Issue

Tags: javascript, csv, google-chrome-extension, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am building a chrome-extension that is required to upload a CSV file to dropbox.

Everything works fine apart of the way the data is structured inside the file that has been successfully uploaded to dropbox.

I am also downloading a local copy of the file and everything looks fine for it, but on dropbox it doesn't seem to recognize the endline characters `("/r/n")`, and it translates the white spaces as `"%20"`. Here is a part of my code where I create the file and upload it to dropbox:

```
function downloadCSV()
{

localStorage["timeStamp"]="inactive";
localStorage["ProfileViews"]="";

// create a csv file with the table data using base64
var encodedUri = encodeURI(localStorage.Table);
var file = 'data:Application/octet-stream,' + encodedUri;
var date = new Date();
// filename contains the unique user id + a timestamp of the current date with year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds
var filename=uniqueID +"  "+date.getYear()+ "-" +date.getMonth() +"-" +date.getDate() +": " +date.getHours() + "." +date.getMinutes() +": "+date.getSeconds()+".csv";

var link = document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("href", file);
link.setAttribute("download", filename);
link.click();

//create a xmlhttp request to send a post request to box.com using the authenthification token
var uploadUrl = 'https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/dropbox/myfolder/'+filename;

// The Box OAuth 2 Header. Add your access token.
var headers = {
    Authorization: 'Bearer '+localStorage.authorization_token
};


$.ajax({
    url: uploadUrl,
    headers: headers,
    type: 'PUT',
    // This prevents JQuery from trying to append the form as a querystring
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: link
}).complete(function ( data ) {
    // Log the JSON response to prove this worked
    console.log(data.responseText);
});




// resets the Table variable
 localStorage["Table"]="";


}
```

I tried to encoded in every possible way but the result is still the same. Any assistance in solving this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what you're trying to do in your code. It looks like you're creating a hyperlink with a URL-encoded version of your data as the href, but then you're passing that `link` variable as the data to an AJAX request... what does that end up doing? You should just pass the data:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: /* the actual data you want to upload here */
    ...
});
```

I can't tell from your code if `localStorage.Table` is the actual CSV data or not. (A comment mentions base64 encoding?) But whatever variable holds the exact CSV data you want in the file should be passed as the `data` parameter on your HTTP request. Don't base64-encode, don't URL encode, etc.

Comment: The reason I encode the data as href is because I want to download a local copy of it. I just noticed now that I am uploading it after I attach a href to it. Thanks for flagging that. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `contentType:'application/octet-stream'`